# Uninstall Fabric for iOS from Mac

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter-fabric

I am facing few linker error while building the Xcode project with Fabric/Crashltytics.

I want to completely remove the Fabric app and then try again.

What are the steps to remove the Fabric completely from Mac including the preferences and caches?

Comment: Please try to build app using device not simulator.

Comment: I tried for both device and simulator but i am getting linker error. One of my team mates upgrade the Crashlytics framework and i am now unable to login into Fabric app on my Mac so i wanted to reinstall everything.

Comment: The presence of the app won't affect the link errors as the frameworks you link against are within your project structure.  Reinstalling the app won't help with this.  Also the Fabric app will upgrade itself automatically.

Answer (score 6):

Remove the Fabric Folder from your system [image]. Go to Your app, and remove `Fabric.framework`. Then follow [this](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/349342-how-do-i-delete-my-app) to remove app from Crashlytics/Fabric. Also delete `Run Script` in `Build Phases`

Comment: How to delete from launchpad?